# node-gyp installation failures on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

- **Node Version**: node -v and `npm -v`

node v8.11.2

npm v6.0.1

- **Platform**: uname -a (UNIX), or `systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version" /C:"System Type"` (Windows)

Windows

- **Compiler**:  (UNIX) or `msbuild /version & cl</code> (Windows) --> Windows
- **Module**:  node canvas

Verbose output (from npm or node-gyp):

I have tried to install node-gyp from npm according to the instructions for windows on the node-gyp repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules

I have python 2.7 installed

I have changed the npm config setting to point to the right version of python

I followed the option2 instructions and I have GTK running correctly. I see the demo widget for GTK when I run the cmd.

I enter the next command:

`node-gyp rebuild --GTK_Root=C:\Users\davidlop\Documents\Software\GTK`

and all I get is: bash: node-gyp: command not found

I have tried every fix, I have uninstalled and reinstalled node npm.

I have followed the instructions to the letter. How do I install this? I am trying to work with node canvas and node-gyp is required... What am I doing wrong?

```

I lost track of the log and where it is. Once I get some progress and a new log I will post.

Also I added my $PATH/users/AppData/Roaming/npm directory to my PATH. The error I get is:

**Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\Git\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js'**

```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have installed `node-gyp` globally. Looking on your issue it seems that **node-gyp.js** file is not available in the specified path.

Node Gyp installation for Windows

```
npm install -g node-gyp
```

After installing node-gyp globally, Open command prompt as an **Administrator** and run the following command to install window build tools.

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

After installation, Run the following command to rebuild your GTK.

```
node-gyp rebuild --GTK_Root=C:\Users\davidlop\Documents\Software\GTK
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found a work around that didnt involve node-gyp so I apologize since I cant get you real feedback. Ill mark as accepted and hope it helps someone else.

Comment: @lopezdp what did u end up doing? I have same problem

Comment: @bluejayke I honestly cant remember, but I think this had something to do with some python work I was doing and I may have been trying to set something up with Anaconda maybe. I believe in this situation I scrapped whatever direction I was going in because this was a nightmare and found a better and more efficient approach. I think I just went with a direct install of JupiterLab. Im thinking this problem goes away with Window's new Linux Subsystem? not sure at all... hope you find your way out of it tho!