# I am trying to install the node-sass but getting error. How can I fix this

Tags: reactjs, typescript, node-sass

While I am trying to install the node-sass I am facing error during installation process. Could someone tell how can I resolve this.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\deepe\OneDrive\Documents\Yajnaseni\POC\language\node_modules\node-gyp
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\deepe\OneDrive\Documents\Yajnaseni\POC\language\node_modules\.node-gyp-fscmffkd
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\deepe\OneDrive\Documents\Yajnaseni\POC\language\node_modules\node-gyp' -> 'C:\Users\deepe\OneDrive\Documents\Yajnaseni\POC\language\node_modules\.node-gyp-fscmffkd'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\deepe\OneDrive\Documents\Yajnaseni\POC\language\node_modules\node-gyp' -> 'C:\Users\deepe\OneDrive\Documents\Yajnaseni\POC\language\node_modules\.node-gyp-fscmffkd'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\deepe\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Yajnaseni\\POC\\language\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\deepe\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Yajnaseni\\POC\\language\\node_modules\\.node-gyp-fscmffkd'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\deepe\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-07T07_55_05_230Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I think this is a dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420537/node-gyp-installation-failures-on-windows

Comment: Did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554646/eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink-c-users-node-modules-node-sass-dele

Comment: Seems to be a permission issue. Have you tried running the command prompt in Administrator mode ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried restarting your system

you can also try this

navigate to node modules folder and delete .node-sass

after that execute this command

```
npm cache verify

npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are in the project when you are trying to install node-sass?

I am not sure if it is related. I seem to have problem getting node-sass 5.0.0 to run with reactJs, I am using node-sass@4.14.1.

Have you tried install the version 4.14.1.

```
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Maduekwe Pedro restart the system. Remane or delete the .scss file in the editor and then do

`npm cache verify`

`npm i node-sass`